# Laravel Query Builder use variables in MySQL for complex select?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, builder, revisionable

How to do this with one mysql request:

```
$revision = $this->Revision->where('batch', $batch)->first();

$revisions = $this->Revision->where('batch','>', $batch)
->where('revisionable_type', $revision->revisionable_type)
->where('revisionable_id', $revision->revisionable_id)
->get();
```

$this->Revision = eloquent model;

others are just columns.

Comment: You just want a raw MySQL query for this? Is there a particular reason? Why are you needing to do it that way?

Comment: i'm not going to use $revision later, so my thoughts are maybe I can make the mysql remember $revision and give me $revisions directly. And Im not interested in raw query as much as in query builder methods.

Comment: @duellsy not directly related to Revisionable, but ok =)

Comment: actually tagged it `revisionable` so I can easily find it later when working on v2 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood your question initially. You can do this by using:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM revisions AS tmpa 
        INNER JOIN revisions AS tmpb 
        ON tmpb.revisionable_type = tmpa.revisionable_type 
        AND tmpb.revisionable_id = tmpa.revisionable_id 
        WHERE tmpa.batch = '$batch'";

DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

Comment: how do I set $r_type, $r_id? I dont have them yet!

Comment: It looks like it will work, but look again in my code, I do 'batch','>', $batch